# Xcode configuration text fields lose focus

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-6.2

I recently upgraded to Xcode 6.2. It seems like there is a weird bug. For example, if I want to change the bundle id, the textfield will lose focus after any character I type.

Is anyone having the same issues? Does anyone know how to fix that?

It's just quite annoying for me, and I guess for anyone else too.

Comment: Got the same bug, very annoying

Comment: We can't do a thing about it. Please file a Radar.

Comment: Intensely annoying, and also how did they not spot that? Imagine releasing an app with a config panel that only allowed one character to be typed?

Comment: Any active radar on this one?

Comment: Got the same with XCode 8

Answer (score 4):

I also think so it's weird thing, and you need to try change bundle id in the Info tab not in General tab

Comment: Editing values directly in Info.plist seems like a good workaround. Although, this still seems like an Xcode bug...

Answer (score 2):

If you get the problem in "General" tab (same to me), you should modify those infos in "Info" tab if possible. That is my workaround for this bug.