# Xcode only allows single character typing in settings

Tags: xcode

This seems like a weird Xcode bug, and I wanted to know whether anyone else is experiencing this and if there's any way to fix it.

On Xcode 6.2, running on either Mavericks or Yosemite, when I go to the project settings by clicking the project name at the top of the left sidebar, I am only allowed to type a single character at a time before the text field I'm typing in stops accepting input. Like I click on the "Version" field under General, I type "1", the 1 shows up in the text field, and then the text field immediately unhighlights. I have to click the text field again to type another character.

This is happening for all of our project files, on all of our computers...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode configuration text fields lose focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101293/xcode-configuration-text-fields-lose-focus)